# Active Record extremely slow after being idle for a few hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I have a Rails 3 app with about 11,000 rows of Podcasts and about 600,000 rows of Episodes in a SQLite database.  It is currently in development and I'm the only client accessing the server.

When I get home from work at the end of the day and make the first request to a podcast's episodes view, the request takes about 10 times longer than usual.  The second request, however, takes the normal amount of time.

I'm not hugely concerned about this specific issue but I'm pretty confident that it's endemic of other issues that may arise when I eventually deploy this app.

Should I switch to MySQL or a nosql database?  Is there anything else I can do?

**EDIT:**
I should add that I'm running Mac OS X web sharing with Passenger as my server.

Thanks,

Harris

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Passenger or some kind of application launcher you might find that the Rails process gets pruned off when idle for extended periods of time. The whole app has to be restarted on the first request, but would perform normally after that.

This is typical of sites that don't get a lot of traffic. You can artificially stimulate a bit of traffic using a `cron` job and `curl` of course.

Usually you can tell if this is the case by looking at your process list and seeing if the `Rails` process is still running.

This will affect even applications with no database.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply.  Can you just explain what you mean by "pruned off"?

Comment: Idle processes are terminated if Passenger deems they are no longer required. I believe this happens faster if there is less system memory available because it would free up resources that might be useful to other processes.